# In what order should Python’s list.__contains__ invoke __eq__?

Tags: python, cpython, pypy

Consider the following Python program:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Foo(%r)' % (self.bar,)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        print('Foo.__eq__(%r, %r)' % (self, other))
        return self.bar == other

foo1 = Foo('A')
foo2 = Foo('B')
assert foo1 not in [foo2]
```

Under CPython 2.7.11 and 3.5.1, it prints:

```
Foo.__eq__(Foo('A'), Foo('B'))
Foo.__eq__(Foo('B'), 'A')
```

But under PyPy 5.3.1 (2.7), it prints:

```
Foo.__eq__(Foo('B'), Foo('A'))
Foo.__eq__(Foo('A'), 'B')
```

Although Python 3.5’s documentation [states](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons) that equality should be symmetric “if possible”, sometimes it is not. In that case, the order of arguments to `Foo.__eq__` becomes important.

So, is the above CPython behavior an implementation detail, or is it a part of `list`’s public interface (meaning that PyPy has a bug)? Please explain why you think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details):

> For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or
>   collections.deque, the expression `x in y` is equivalent to `any(x is
>   e or x == e for e in y)`.

The other examples in the same section show the same ordering for the equality test. This suggests that the comparison should be `item_maybe_in_list.__eq__(item_actually_in_list)`, in which case this could be considered a bug in PyPy. Additionally, CPython is the reference implementation, so in any discrepancy that version wins!

That said, you should raise it with that community to see how they feel about it.

Comment: Wait, where does it say that `x == e` has to be `x.__eq__(e)`?

Comment: @Rawing https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov ah. It seems ***I*** should be reading the docs more thoroughly.

Comment: @Rawing it should at least *start* there, although `return NotImplemented` may cause some fallback behaviour.

Comment: For future reference: I reported this as [PyPy issue #2352](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues/2352/list__contains__-compares-objects-in-wrong).